# script needs to add another loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
while read -r server port line
do  
  echo server: "$server" port: "$port"  
  ssh -qn "$server" "netstat -ntl | grep -E \"\b$port\b\""
  echo
done < demo
```

this is the script that will give the below output

```
server: Jan port: 8000
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1505/httpd

server: feb port: 8000
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1505/httpd
```

I need to add another command which will run ps -ef | grep -i 1505 process id of https command, unable to do so. need expert advice.

Accepted output 
1Step. login to the server 
2Step. run the first command netstat which gives the output of process id
3Step. ps -ef | grep -i 1505 "processid" runs it will take that process id output & run the command ps

```
server: Jan port: 8000
tcp   0 0 0.0.0.0:8000 0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN 1505/httpd

root      1421 15033  0 13:38 pts/16   00:00:00 grep -i 1505


server: feb port: 8000
tcp   0 0 0.0.0.0:8000 0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN 1505/httpd

root      1421 15033  0 13:38 pts/16   00:00:00 grep -i 1505
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Paste your expected output.

Comment: Kate added the details, please have a look.

Comment: How would you write the two `netstat` and `ps` commands not in your script? Do you know? Also if you already have the pid piping the output of `ps` to `grep` is pointless. Just limit `ps` to the pid you want with `-p`.

Comment: I will get the PID from the netstat command script should read the PID fro mthe output & run the ps command, I am unable to do that. need help

Comment: hope you have understand what I need